# Can the identity function be expressed as a countable-linear combination of indicator functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Question.** Can the function $$\mathrm{id} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \qquad \mathrm{id}_\mathbb{R}(x) = x$$
>
> be expressed as a countable-linear combination of indicator functions of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

*Remark.* One idea for constructing such a thing is to try to find a function $a : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) \qquad x = \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}}a_q[x<q],$$

where the square brackets connote the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). But it's not really clear how to choose the $a_q$'s.

Honestly, I think the answer is probably "no."

Ideas, anyone?

I'm also interested in the (simpler?) problem where $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: Using a countable linear combination, you should discuss convergence: Do you want to have finite linear combinations at every point $r \in \mathbb{R}$ (as almost all indicator functions are zero at this point), or do you allow infinitely many sets containing the same point, but in a way that the coefficients converge properly?

Comment: @Bemte, lets allow infinitely many sets to contain the same point. We just want the sum-of-indicator-functions to converge pointwise, methinks.

Comment: Then the next question would be if you allow negative coefficients in the linear combinations. This might help with convergence (e.g. in some inclusion/exclusion scheme), but will of course further complicate the whole thing.

Comment: @Bemte, yes, sure, they can be infinite. And we only require conditional convergence, not absolute convergence. To do this properly might require well-ordering $\mathbb{Q}$, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix for each $0\leq x<1$ some binary representation (for example, say that you use for each $x$ the representation not containing an infinite tail of ones).

Then 
$$
x=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-j} [j\text{th digit in binary representation of }x\text{ is }1]
$$ for any $0\leq x<1$, as follows pretty much directly from the definition of binary representations.

To extend this to all of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq}$ just extend the sum to $-\infty$.

To extend it to all of $\mathbb{R}$ just add the same representation  with replacements $x\mapsto -x$ and $2^{-j}\mapsto -2^{-j}$